# Trying to deploy app via Capistrano for first time, having problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am trying to deploy a Rails app via Capistrano but am having problems. The messages that get returned in Terminal are as follows:

```
    victor$ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:victory/PUM.git HEAD"
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:98: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.5.19/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb:98: command not found: git ls-remote git@github.com:victory/PUM.git HEAD
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /passenger/nginx/pumpl/releases/20101020025555; true"
    servers: ["188.126.236.269"]
Password:
```

I tried to do a Google search but am having a bit of trouble finding a good answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

I just switched to a new Mac that didn't have Xcode installed. This is why Macports was not working correctly. I installed Xcode and after that, I am now able to deploy just fine.

Answer (score 7):

Would seem your remote installation lacks git. 
Have you tried doing a

```
cap deploy:check
```

To check the environment and a

```
cap deploy:setup
```

To setup the required files?